# ExpressJS Static Serve Images

Tags: node.js, express

I know there are a bunch of questions on this topic but none seem to directly answer my problem.

I am trying to static serve images from NodeJS using ExpressJS. I've already successfully statically served a CSS file using:

```
this.app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "style")));
```

and accessing the file at URL/file.css. However when I try and do something similar for images using:

```
this.app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, "images")));
```

and I try and access the file using URL/images/file.jpg - I just get an error saying

> Cannot GET /images/file.jpg

I've also tried variants without the /images/ similar to the way I've done style and get the same problem. Unsure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: are you sure the path is resulting out of the path.join and "images" has a file.jpg? I tried the above code on a sample program and it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was obvious but subtle. I was compiling typescript from ./ and putting it into /dist and sass from /style into /dist/style so I put my images folder at the root level, rather than inside dist. Problem solved.